# How to generate barcode font (code128) not image

Tags: visual-studio-2010, barcode, telerik-reporting

I have an application that generates barcode in image format and it is read by some devices and fails in others.
The problem now that the barcode image is pixilated so the barcode reader can't read it and i have decided to change barcode from image to font to overcome this problem as font barcode is readable from all readers (that I am using).

I face now a problem, when I setup the driver of the printer (Zebra TLP) at my PC (64-bit) and set it as a default printer, the font Code128 appeared in fonts list at MS Office Word application but in VS2010 doesn't appear, I need to use the font of the printer (Code128) to use it and generate barcode. How can I do that?

I don't know if the problem is clear to you or not? But I have to generate a font barcode in .net 2010 at Telerik reports.

Comment: I need a help please each time i post a question i suffer to get an answer where can i go ????????

Comment: The issue is not related to Telerik, the font "Code128" is not appeared in fonts list for any control in .net not telerik controls only

Comment: Then get yourself another font, a real TrueType version of it.  Avoid OpenType.

Comment: How can i do that ? i don't know how to get TrueType version can you help me please?

Comment: Same issue here. I can see the font in Word, excel, and notepad, but I cannot see it in any program compiled from VS 2010 or 2008. I tried the font from below, it's still the same result. Did you solve this issue? How? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I downloaded a code128 true type font [**here**](http://www.jtbarton.com/Barcodes/code128.ttf) and have used it in a few apps since. [**This page**](http://www.jtbarton.com/Barcodes/Code128.aspx) also gave good data for computing checksums for code128.

Comment: But are you sure that this font is compatible with printer "Zebra"?

Comment: I tried this font but i have a problem in the size of the barcode, when i raise the font size to enlarge the barcode lines to fit its container's width, it expanded to a fixed width less than its container width then wrap the lines.... how can i solve this issue?

Comment: How can i calculate checksum for Code128?

Comment: Thanks for you inspite you didn't give me full answer and follow me in my inquires but thanks and +1 vote and acceptance for your care

Comment: @Ahmy sorry for the delay I was away for a bit, take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11179765/1062992)