# How do I convert a single char to a string?

Tags: c#, string, casting, char

I'd like to enumerate a `string` and instead of it returning `chars` I'd like to have the iterative variable be of type `string`. This probably isn't possible to have the iterative type be a `string` so what is the most efficient way to iterate through this string?

Do I need to create a new `string` object with each iteration of the loop or can I perform a cast somehow?

```
String myString = "Hello, World";
foreach (Char c in myString)
{
    // what I want to do in here is get a string representation of c
    // but I can't cast expression of type 'char' to type 'string'
    String cString = (String)c; // this will not compile
}
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use the .ToString() Method

```
String myString = "Hello, World";
foreach (Char c in myString)
{
    String cString = c.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Consider using the C# types `string` and `char` instead of the CLR types. The same in the end but arguably more correct in C#.

Comment: @andleer You are right, I just modified OP's example code to show the ToString Method.

Comment: The comment was directed at him, not you.  No worries.

Comment: This is all well and good, but *why* doesn't this work? No one seems to explain this.

Comment: @druciferre What do you mean by *why* doesn't this work? It works fine for me.

Comment: @tom_mai78101, honestly I have no idea why I asked that. It was over a year ago. I suspect the answer has been modified and because other comments deleted.

Comment: @druciferre This answer has not been modified since I made it in 2012.

Comment: Best guess is someone commented "this doesn't work" and their comment has since been deleted.

Comment: @tom_mai78101, looking over the question again I think I was complaining none of the answers explain why casting a `char` to a `string` doesn't work or apparently compile.

Comment: @druciferre Oh I see. There is no implicit conversion from anything to char in .NET, and vice versa I guess.

Comment: I think the question @druciferre was asking is why (or rather, how) using C# types versus CLR types is "more correct." That's what I'm wondering, anyway!

Comment: Seems to work, but why can't we just use the *built-in syntactic way* to do explicit conversions? e.g. `string s = (string) c`

Comment: Interestingly, VB freely allows you to assign a Char to a String variable. Behind-the-scenes it uses `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToString`, but the VB syntax supports it in an intuitive manner.

Comment: (I'd guess that `char` is a value type and `string` is a reference type, so that's why you can't easily turn a `char` into a `string` in C#)

Comment: @andleer Jeffrey Richter recommends using the CLR type name rather than the C# keyword in his book "CLR Via C#". Some reasons why: the names are more descriptive (consider Int64 and Int32 vs long and int). You can use the CLR type name in all languages that target .NET, the same is not necessarily true for C# keywords.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner In the same way, one can argue in favor of code analysis: "Use language keywords instead of framework type names for type references (IDE0049)". In the end it's an option. The default is to prefer the language keyword. Personally, I put more weight to the default of the rule, than someone's opinion.

Comment: @Rob IDE0049 doesn't provide an explanation as to why that way is better, it just says "do it". Jeffrey Richter, who btw is not just "someone" but was the lead consultant for building the .NET Framework, provides reasons as to why using the CLR type name is better.

Comment: The reasons of the referenced person, which are fine BTW, still amounts to an opinion. One may agree or not. As to my favoring the default rule choice, is that it was likely chosen over time, and by more than a single person, also involved and with reasons.

Answer (score 15):

You have two options. Create a `string` object or call `ToString` method.

```
String cString = c.ToString();
String cString2 = new String(c, 1); // second parameter indicates
                                    // how many times it should be repeated
```

Answer (score 8):

With C# 6 interpolation:

```
char ch = 'A';
string s = $"{ch}";
```

This shaves a few bytes. :)

Comment: String interpolation efficiency is costly though. Better to just do `new String(ch,1)`.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the obvious thing to do is this:

```
String cString = c.ToString()
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a new string from the char.

```
 String cString = new String(new char[] { c });
```

or

```
 String cString = c.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently wanted to know which approach was the fastest, so I benchmarked 5 approaches.

The answer is that you should use `new String(myChar,1)`, for the fastest times:

```
|           Method |      Mean |    Error |    StdDev | Rank |   Gen0 | Allocated |
|----------------- |----------:|---------:|----------:|-----:|-------:|----------:|
|        NewString |  10.65 ns | 0.502 ns |  1.473 ns |    1 | 0.0031 |      16 B |
|        AddString |  11.83 ns | 0.845 ns |  2.466 ns |    2 | 0.0030 |      16 B |
|     CharToString |  12.26 ns | 0.662 ns |  1.951 ns |    2 | 0.0030 |      16 B |
| NewStringPointer |  33.03 ns | 1.382 ns |  3.988 ns |    3 | 0.0030 |      16 B |
|      Interpolate | 119.31 ns | 5.351 ns | 15.525 ns |    4 | 0.0083 |      44 B |
```

Where the 5 methods are:

```
public string CharToString(char input) => input.ToString();
public string Interpolate(char input) => $"{input}";
public string AddString(char input) => input + "";
public string NewString(char input) => new String(input,1);
public string NewStringPointer(char input)
{
    unsafe
    {
        return new String(& input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also test having a table of 256 strings (1 for each char) then copying one of them to get a new one? (maybe like cloning if its read-only use or deep copying if its write+read?)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik what do you think you're referring to w.r.t. cloning, and read-only/read-write? None of those concepts are even slightly applicable to `string`s.

Comment: Like a singleton with a string field and changing its field depending on use case.

Comment: ??? I don't have the faintest idea what you're talking about. But this benchmarking is pretty trivial to run; feel free to go and try it yourself :) Search Nick Chapsas Benchmark.NET

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCharsAsStrings(this string value)
{
    return value.Select(c =>
           {
                //not good at all, but also a working variant
                //return string.Concat(c);

                return c.ToString();
           });
}
```

and loop through strings:

```
string s = "123456";
foreach (string c in s.GetCharsAsStrings())
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use + with empty string `""`, please check the below code:

```
char a = 'A';
//a_str is a string, the value of which is "A".
string a_str = ""+a;
```

Comment: Looks like (ugly) javascript code

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

`String s = new String(new char[] { 'c' });`

Comment: There is no ctor that takes just char

Answer (score 0):

```
String cString = c.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this code? Won't it be faster?

```
string myString = "Hello, World";
foreach( char c in myString )
{
    string cString = new string( c, 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> probably isn't possible to have the iterative type be a string

Sure it is:

```
foreach (string str in myString.Select(c => c.ToString())
{
...
}
```

Any of the suggestions in the other answers can be substituted for `c.ToString()`. Probably the most efficient by a small hair is `c => new string(c, 1)`, which is what `char.ToString()` probably does under the hood.